# Is it possible to have 2 different networks using 2 Routers that are both connected to 1 Modem-Router using Bridge?

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem, bridge

I'm trying to set up two separate private networks connected to one Internet Service Provider. My ISP has supplied 1 Modem-Router (X) and then I have 2 other different Routers (Y & Z).

I have already successfully set up a similar thing before using "non-bridge" as the Switch Mode for the Modem-Router (X). But constant DDOS attacks and Port Scans on the Modem-Router (X) made that type of connection impossible. Only "bridge" connection type seems to work but only with 1 Router (Y) connected. My question is, how do I add one more Router (Z) in this kind of set up and is it even possible? Kindly see the network diagram below that I have in mind.

Home Network Diagram:

> [image]

Comment: Is it your intention to isolate the two sub-nets? Why do you think that this config is more resistant to DDOS (and why would you be attacked)?

Comment: Yes, I need to separate the 2 networks. This is so I can easily reset the configuration and/or firmware of any router without affecting the connections of each network. The 1st network would connect devices from trusted users and has strict security settings. The 2nd network would be for guests and for use of software and allowed visits to websites that are normally restricted on the 1st network.

Comment: The router used by the 1st network has higher specs and updated security software. The router for the 2nd network is quite old and its intended to be regularly reset. Not sure if the DDOS attacks are deliberate. I have a hunch it is caused by a persistent Malware that infected one of our connected devices making it part of the botnet.

Comment: If the better router supports VLANs, you could do without the old one.

Comment: I think VLANs could work... But its added complexity for what I need. I just opted to use a manual LAN Switch Splitter Selector Box. Thanks for the suggestions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With ordinary consumer and entry level commercial gear, you cannot do as you have drawn.

> I have already successfully set up a similar thing before using
> "non-bridge" as the Switch Mode

I think that would use a second IP address from the ISP. I have done this as well.

For one External IP Address, you can have one ordinary router and then chain your other routers and devices onto the main router.  I do this as well.

DDOS security should be handled by your main router and top grade routers do accomplish this.

Comment: MAC Cloning worked for me for Routers Y & Z if using "Router Mode" for the ISP's Modem (X). But the Internet connection speed still degrades and becomes intermittent similarly if only one Router is connected to the Modem. I guess this happens because Modem is old and has low specs that it can't handle too many DDOS attacks.

Comment: Do you have a suggested budget-friendly commercial-grade Wireless Router that can handle these DDOS attacks?

Comment: I have another idea but I'm not sure if it will work. What if I directly connected a Switch instead to the Modem (X) and then connected both Y & Z Routers to the Switch, Would you know if I can still use "bridge mode" for the Modem (X) and have the other 2 connected Routers work?

Comment: I'm kinda worried of connecting the old Router (Z) to the other newer Router (Y) because I think the old one still has unremovable Malware even after a hard factory reset and firmware upgrade. Thus I'm aiming for a direct connection to the Modem for both Routers and just regularly reset Router Z every time it experiences problems.

Comment: Routers (at least any decent one I have seen) do not have malware,   "What if I directly connected a Switch instead to the Modem (X) and then connected both Y & Z "   <-- With a single external IP, I do not think that will work. Can you get a decent router?

Comment: I have a suspicion that using Merlin as firmware may have trashed my old Router to the point that any hard reset and/or reverting to its official firmware cannot fix it. Random Chinese characters appear on our Smart TV if connected to that Router's LAN port. Anyhow I already bought a new Router w/ higher specs and just opted to use a manual LAN Switch Selector Box to segregate our Network. That seems to work out for now. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  That is similar to my suggestions earlier.